# get python class file from s3 bucket and use it inside aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to get python file from s3 bucket and use it in my AWS Lambda.
for eg file test.py file is stored in s3 bucket on some location.
will use boto3 get_object() to get contents of the py file.
now need to execute the py file in lambda?

Comment: That sounds like a very dangerous task :) What if a python file placed there contains code that will delete of all your AWS resources? Unless of course your AWS Lambda policies are restricted. If you are ready for the consequences, which could even be worse than what I said, you might want to look into [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). USE THIS WITH CAUTION, PLEASE! Better yet redesign your system.

Comment: Do you wish to do this because you want to frequently update the class file in S3? Have you considered simply including it in your AWS Lambda function, or perhaps as a Lambda Layer?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - main reason to use this approach is to avoid multiple deployment of lambda and layers

Comment: that is a very silly reason. Considering you can edit python lambda code directly in the console - if you are doing testing and trying to discover how the cloud works then this is the better option.

Better yet, set up a Cloudformation or CDK stack or SAM template to deploy for you - even just using the aws cli to do so. That way you dont have a very big potential security issue in your account.

Comment: Finally, if you absolutely must, look into Elastic File System.  you can attach this to your lambda and see this as an extension of your lambdas file system, even importing modules in a proper pythonic way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using this and not Lambda Layers? Is more effective and cheap. You just need to import your .py code from the Layer.

Anyway, if you keep want to do this, you just need to name the get object result, convert it into "text" and then call it in the Lambda function.

Example:

```py
mycode = boto3.get_object(---)
mycode.toString or something like that

def lambda_handler():
    mycode (try to exclude the def-lambda_handler in your "mycode" code)
```